# How to embed an action from a sub-namespaced controller in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to render an action which is in a sub-namespaced controller from within a Twig view in Symfony 2.

The **problem** is: The render helper cannot find the controller/action because it's in a namespace below *Controller*.

This is my controller:
**src/Acme/Bundle/TestBundle/Controller/FirstModule/ExampleController.php**

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Controller\FirstModule;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function exampleAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('AcmeTestBundle:FirstModuleExample:example.html.twig');
    }

    public function embedAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('AcmeTestBundle:FirstModuleExample:embed.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This is my view:
**src/Acme/Bundle/TestBundle/Resources/views/FirstModuleExample/example.html.twig**

```
{% render "AcmeTestBundle:Example:embed" %}
// or
{% render "Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Controller\FirstModule\Example:example" %}
// or
{% render "Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Controller\FirstModule\ExampleController:exampleAction" %}
```

I have read the [Embedding Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) documentation but no clue there how to handle Controllers that are in a sub-namespace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these should work.  Remember, backslashes in strings need to be escaped (i.e., doubled)

```
{% render "AcmeTestBundle:FirstModule\\Example:embed" %}
```

or

```
{% render "Acme\\Bundle\\TestBundle\\Controller\\FirstModule\\ExampleController::embedAction" %}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Shame Symfony does not include this in the documentation.

Comment: They do, just not on that page. After you've spent time with their view/controller system you become pretty comfortable referencing either by `Bundle:Controller:Action` or `FQCN::actionName`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
{% render "AcmeTestBundle:FirstModule/Example:embed" %}
```

or this?

```
{% render "AcmeTestBundle:FirstModule\\Example:embed" %}
```

Comment: Interesting, page got rendered and got following error on page: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Controller\FirstModule\ExampleController in ...`

Comment: After clearing the cache I got another error: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The autoloader expected class "Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Controller\FirstModule/ExampleController" to be defined in file "../src/Acme/Bundle/TestBundle/Controller/FirstModule/ExampleController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.") in AcmeTestBundle:FirstModuleExample:example.html.twig at line 1.`

Comment: I updated my answer with yet another example (try replacing directory separator with namespace separator).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use backslash-notation but I haven't tried it since I practice to put all controllers into single namespace (which is bad if you have a lot of them).

Something like this:

```
{% render "Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Controller\FirstModule\Example:example" %}
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You have requested a non-existent service "acmebundletestbundlecontrollerfirstmoduleexample".") in AcmeTestBundle:FirstModule:example.html.twig at line 1.`